# Query to Change column (varchar) with dd/mm/yy to DateTime

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a few new tables where I am now doing a bulk insert from a .txt file
there is about 5,000 rows of information. The problem I have is that, I have
no idea how to convert a column with varchar to a datetime... I am somewhat new to 
SQL, so it's a new challenge. there is 7 columns with that I can do a bulk insert
to varchar but not datetime due to format. 
12/06/89, 03/06/07,05/06/68 and so on
I would like to make this a DateTime. If anyone can offer a solution I would 
be very thankful.

I am using sql 2008 r2 web

Answer (score 0):

For eg.

```
select convert(datetime,'3/13/41',1)
```

Comment: Both the date and the format specifier in your example have to do with the `mm/dd/yy` format, and the OP's problem is about `dd/mm/yy`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT CAST('12/06/89' AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: would that work for all 5000 records? or would I have to make one for each new date?

Answer (score 0):

from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx

```
 -- Set date format to day/month/year. 
SET DATEFORMAT dmy; 
GO 
DECLARE @datevar datetime2 = '31/12/2008 09:01:01.1234567'; 
SELECT @datevar; 
GO
```